# A closed hyperplane separating two sets , also separates their closure

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, continuity, normed-spaces

Suppose the hyperplane $[f=\alpha]$ seperates $A$ and $B$ which are subsets of a normed space $E$ .

I thought of considering two cases , one which assumes that $A$ and $B$ are closed (which is the trivial case) , and the other is if both aren't closed.

For the second case , let $x\in \bar{A}\setminus A$ and $y \in \bar{B} \setminus B$ , then by definition of closure in a metric space , there exists two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $\bar{A} \setminus A$ and $\bar{B} \setminus B$ respectively such that $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $y_n\rightarrow y$.

As $[f=\alpha]$ is closed then $f$ is continuous, then $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ and $f(y_n)\rightarrow f(y)$ .

Also , $f(x_n)\leq \alpha$ and $f(y_n)\geq \alpha$
(Definition of hyperplane)

So we have that $(f(x_n))$ and $(f(y_n))$ are convergent and bounded sequences, (upper and lower bounds resp.) then their limits are bounded by same $\alpha$ , hence the result.

My quenstion is, should I consider more cases ? And is my work fine ? And also , if the hyperplane strictly separates the two sets, will the proof differ ?

Comment: The "strict" case is false: is $H$ strictly separates two sets, it does not strictly separate their closures.

Comment: Your proof is fine.